# Accessing Objective C AppDelegate String in Swift Class returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsnumber

I'm attempting to access a NSNumber value from my ObjectiveC AppDelegate in/using a Swift class however it continuously returns nil on the Swift side of things - however it is populated in the Objective C class (I believe it is due to how I am calling it in Swift - even though it is found using code completion - for some reason it is still getting lost when passing between the two).

Any suggestions are appreciated.

### Objective C AppDelegate.m:

```
...

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
{
    theNotification = notification;
    NSDictionary *aps = (NSDictionary *)[notification objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSNumber *chatId = [aps objectForKey:@"chatId"];

    }

    ...
```

### Objective C AppDelegate.h:

```
... 

@property (nonatomic) NSNumber* chatId;

...
```

### Swift:

```
 class func clientChatSendMessage(_ chatId: NSNumber, message: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, NSError?) -> ()) -> URLSessionTask {


    let oCchatId: AppDelegate = AppDelegate()
    let chatSessionId:NSNumber  = oCchatId.chatId
```

Comment: You can refer using swift in objective c https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/UsingSwiftInObjectiveC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you create new variable  `NSNumber *chatId = [aps objectForKey:@"chatId"];`

Try this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
{
    theNotification = notification;
    NSDictionary *aps = (NSDictionary *)[notification objectForKey:@"aps"];
    self.chatId = [aps objectForKey:@"chatId"];

}
```

**EDIT**

As **Caleb** said in comments

> I think the new instance of AppDelegate is also a problem. It should
>   be accessed with UIApplication.shared.delegate.chatId

So you need to change this too

```
class func clientChatSendMessage(_ chatId: NSNumber, message: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, NSError?) -> ()) -> URLSessionTask {


    let oCchatId: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate() as! AppDelegate
    let chatSessionId:NSNumber  = oCchatId.chatId
```

Comment: I think the new instance of `AppDelegate` is also a problem. It should be accessed with `UIApplication.shared.delegate.chatId`

Comment: Yes, I did not notice this at once

Comment: I tried as you suggested however I'm getting a new error stating: Value of type 'UIApplicationDelegate?' has no member 'chatId' ...which can't be right - I've clearly defined it in AppDelegate.m and AppDelegate.h (I can upload a copy of the project if you'd like - this is bizarre)

Also - the point at which it becomes nil is in the Swift class  at the line: let chatSessionId:NSNumber  = oCchatId.chatId 

when calling it at NSNumber *chatId = [aps objectForKey:@"chatId"]; I can always see the value (when using my method or yours)

Comment: I have small changes in **clientChatSendMessage** please try this.

Comment: I apologize - earlier I thought this was resolved but it isn't - when I call chatSessionId it is still null/empty using the example you posted above (only in the swift side - objective c it is there)